# disable warning 'the thrown object must be an instance of the exception'

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using phpStorm. And I have the following piece of code written by Kohana framework:

```
throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,
    'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
    array(':uri' => $this->request->uri())
)->request($this->request);
```

The problem is that phpStorm considers this piece of code invalid and displays the following message: `the thrown object must be an instance of the exception`. I don't like it because it shows the entire project up to first directory invalid.

Is there any way I can work around it without changing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot -- this error is produced by Annotator and not individual Inspection (individual inspection can be suppressed).

Accordingly to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14734 this is marked as "Won't fix". You can add your comments there or even submit new ticket if so desired.

Answer (score 4):

i meet the same error

**your Exception class must extend from `\Exception` ;
instead  of extend from `Exception` ;**

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I added backslash to the name of the class that's being extended as suggested:
`class TypedException extends \Exception
{
//class code
}`
and warnings disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like PhpStorm gets "stuck" thinking the project is a PHP7 project, even if you change the PHP version in Settings. I solved this by removing the `.idea` directory altogether, and reopening the directory as a fresh project.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when having worked on a PHP 7 project and then switched back to a PHP 5.6 project. In "project settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHP language level" I switched from PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.5 and the error message disappeared. I then switched back to PHP 5.6 and it didn't popup again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (i'm development on laravel framework) you should add slash before extends class Exception or Throwable. It is works for me. See code bellow

```
class ProcessIncomplete extends \Exception {}
```

By the way, I'm also using PHPStorm ide